# is it possible to change colored areas into black and white where other areas remain same?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I do working in  image processing using opencv package. In my image,want to invert the colored regions into binary color where else not affecting other pixels.

**For explanation in this image i wish to change the blue regions into white and inside texts has to be in black colors by not affecting below regions.**

[image]

Comment: Is this in CSS?

Comment: is it possible the answer is always yes ... is it feasible is probably a better question and I am skeptical that there would be a good common solution ... it would be quite easy if it was always a 15px bar at the top or something

Comment: @RingGamesCompany no its an image Im sure

Comment: no its in  python @RingGamesCompany.

Comment: @JoranBeasley please upload the answer

Comment: Ok. i can not help

Comment: @RingGamesCompany , Anyway thanks for your support.

Comment: Any time! I will follow you

Comment: _is it possible_ Probably, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC, If the question is not asked in proper way then edit it as you think it should be

Comment: @Mvk1312 _If the question is not asked in proper way then edit it as you think it should be_ If the question is severely lacking in information, then how is anyone else supposed to edit it? If we understand enough to make substantial edits then the question can't be that unclear in the first place, right?

Comment: If you are interested in processing images and specifically analysing colours, the very first thing you should do is understand that JPEGs are generally very poor for colour because they favour the lightness channel and generally down-sample and discard significant aspects of the colour channel. So, you should try and save your screen-grabs as PNGs where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('A.jpg')
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w=img.shape[1]
m=np.mean(img, axis=1)
m=m>150
mask_img=np.repeat(m, w)
mask_img.shape=img.shape
a=255-img^(255*mask_img)
cv2.imwrite('A_out.jpg', a)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

convert it to rgb value array

```
rgbVals = getRGBValues(im) # no idea how to do this offhand
for row in range(20): # first 20 px
    for col,px in enumerate(rgbVals[row]):
        rgbVals[row][col] = (255,255,255) if rgbVals[row][col] != (255,255,255) else (0,0,0)
new_im = rgbVals_to_image(rgbVals)
```

here it is more exact

```
>>> from scipy import misc
>>> a = misc.imread("D:\\Downloads\\pic.jpg") # the image from your post
>>> #get the white(ish) cells
... mask = (a[0:20,:,0] > 160) & (a[0:20,:,1] > 160) & (a[0:20,:,1] > 160)
>>> a[0:20][mask] = [0,0,0] # make the white cells black
>>> a[0:20][~mask] = [255,255,255] # make the rest white
>>> misc.imsave('out.jpg',a)
```

The output isnt perfect :/ (all the 0:20 means we are just looking at the first 20 rows of pixels )
[image]